# Class Model in Angular 2 not working

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a small problem.

I declare a class ITask.

[image: Class ITask in file Task Model]

Then import it to `component` CreateTask. Create a variable `taskSend` = new ITask();

[image]

And log it in ngOnInit(), **it don't have some properties of class ITask.**

In View have some error : `CreateTaskComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined`

[image]

**Update:**

File `create-task.component.html`

```
<div class="create-task-page container mt-4">
  <div class="d-block my-3">
    <h2 class="page-title my-3">{{ 'PAGES.TASK.HEADING.CREATE_TASK' | translate }}</h2>
  </div>
  <section class="mt-3">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="task_name">{{ 'PAGES.TASK.LABEL.TASK_NAME' | translate }}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task_name" aria-describedby="taksHelp" [(ngModel)]="taskSend.task.Name" placeholder="{{ 'PAGES.TASK.PLACEHOLDER.TASK_NAME' | translate }}">
        <small id="taksHelp" class="form-text text-muted">{{ 'PAGES.TASK.HINT.TASK_NAME' | translate }}</small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">{{ 'PAGES.TASK.LABEL.DESCRIPTION' | translate }}</label>
        <td-text-editor value="content" [options]="options"></td-text-editor>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tags">{{ 'PAGES.TASK.LABEL.TAGS' | translate }}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tags" placeholder="{{ 'PAGES.TASK.PLACEHOLDER.TAGS' | translate }}" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ 'SYSTEM.ACTIONS.LABEL.SUBMIT' | translate }}</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably you have some binding in your `CreateTaskComponent.html`.

As said in the error you mentioned.

Comment: can you post the `CreateTaskComponent.html` ?

Comment: @AbduManaz: I was update CreateTaskComponent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the error. 'Name' is a property from ITaskModel, and ITask has was a property of that type. 
On ITask use the constructor to instantiate the other classes you also defined.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: yes, i use contructor for class, it working. every class in typescript, prototies r undefine

Answer (score 0):

Your `iTask` class doesn't contain a property called `Name`. But you are trying to access it in your html. on line no. 9

```
[(ngModel)]="taskSend.task.Name"
```

This is the issue.
To resolve it either add `Name` property to `iTask` or change the `ngModel` binded variable.

Comment: Sorry, you can see in log (i was log `taskSend` in `ngOnInit()` ) it don't have properties of class ITask.

Comment: i try remove some properties of ITask. `export class ITask {
    time: string;
    description: string;
    users: number;
    language: string;
}`
But it not working.

Comment: @AnhNC you are trying to access a property of class `ITask` - `Name`, which is not present in the class `ITask`. That is the issue as I have mentioned. Removing the properties from ITask wont work as you are already referring to something that is not there in the class. You have to either add the property or change the referencing variable